# Is this Laravel session handling inconsistency a bug?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I am using Laravel 5.5.  I have configured a number of authentication guards that use the session driver.  Each has a different user provider.  The providers all use the eloquent driver, but each creates a different type of user, e.g. `App\User\Staff`, `App\User\Customer`.

In addition I have setup subdomain routing for each of my user types, e.g. `staff.mydomain.com`, `customer.mydomain.com`.  Today I was delighted to find that if I log in at one sub domain, that information is not shared with the other domain (by default anyhow).  This means that I can be logged in on one browser tab as a staff member, and on another browser tab as a customer.

Or at least that's what I thought.

This works fine with the file session driver, however was unpredictable when using the database driver.  The database showed new session records for each sub-domain, as I would expect, and the session ID's were refreshed on login.  When I checked the `Auth::check()` though, in one tab it showed correctly (i.e. logged in for one guard, and guest on the others).  In the other tab it showed guest on all guards.

I tried this back and forth (file/database session driver), and the file driver was consistently consistent, and the database driver was consistently flaky.  Is this a bug?  Or is there something I am missing about session-based authentication and sub-domains?

Comment: Maybe you don't have a web middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging I finally sorted this out.

The sub-domains were unrelated to the problem.  The problem was that I used the the default session tables produced by `artisan session:table` command.  It creates a `user_id` field as an integer type.  My user ID's are uuid.

I am pasting this here as a cautionary tale!